# pyautogui.moveTo does not seem to generate a mouse event

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyhook

I use pyautogui to test much of the functionality in my python application. It seems to work fine for left mouse down, up, and right down and up, as well as key down, and keyup. However, when I am see no mouse events for the mouse move calls.

Why not?
How can I test the functionality of my software that has hooked into mouse move events?

```
import pyHook
import threading
import win32con
import pythoncom
import time
import pyautogui

class WindowsHooksWrapper(object):
    """
    Provides a means to subscribe to keyboard and mouse events via Windows Hooks

    It is important to note that:
    * A thread specific hook (one that is not injected via dll injection) must be registered on the
      same thread with the windows msg pump or it will not work and no indication of error is given
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.consuming_keyboard_events = False
        self.consuming_mouse_events = False
        self.hook_manager = None
        self.started = False
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_proc)

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop()

    def start(self):
        if self.started:
            self.stop()

        self.started = True
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if not self.started:
            return

        self.started = False
        self.thread.join()

    def consume_mouse_events(self, should_consume_events):
        """
        Tell the windows hooks wrapper to consume mouse events or not.
        Consumed events will not be passed to other hooks or the process they were intended for.
        Injected events will be passed on.
        :param should_consume_events: set to True to consume mouse events. Otherwise, False
        """
        if should_consume_events:
            print 'Consuming mouse events'
        else:
            print 'No longer consuming mouse events'

        self.consuming_mouse_events = should_consume_events

    def consume_keyboard_events(self, should_consume_events):
        """
        Tell the windows hooks wrapper to consume keyboard events or not.
        Consumed events will not be passed to other hooks or the process they were intended for.
        Injected events will be passed on.
        :param should_consume_events: set to True to consume keyboard events. Otherwise, False
        """
        if should_consume_events:
            print 'Consuming keyboard events'
        else:
            print 'No longer consuming keyboard events'
        self.consuming_keyboard_events = should_consume_events

    def on_keyboard_event(self, event):
        """
        Called back from pyHooks library on a keyboard event
        :param event: event passed from pyHooks
        :return: True if we are to pass the event on to other hooks and the process it was intended
         for. False to consume the event.
        """
        # Provide a means to stop consuming events while we are consuming all input
        if event.KeyID == win32con.VK_ESCAPE:
            self.consuming_keyboard_events = False
            self.consuming_mouse_events = False
            # Consume the event
            print 'Escape key hit. Turning input blocking off.'
            return False

        if not self.consuming_keyboard_events or event.Injected:
            print 'MessageName:', event.MessageName
            print 'Message:', event.Message
            print 'Time:', event.Time
            print 'Window:', event.Window
            print 'WindowName:', event.WindowName
            print 'Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii)
            print 'Key:', event.Key
            print 'KeyID:', event.KeyID
            print 'ScanCode:', event.ScanCode
            print 'Extended:', event.Extended
            print 'Injected:', event.Injected
            print 'Alt', event.Alt
            print 'Transition', event.Transition
            print '---'
            # Send the event to other handlers and its target
            return True
        else:
            # Consume the event. Any other hooks will not receive the event, nor will the process
            # the event was intended for.
            print 'Consumed keyboard event'
            return False

    def on_mouse_event(self, event):
        """
        Called back from pyHooks library on a mouse event
        :param event: event passed from pyHooks
        :return: True if we are to pass the event on to other hooks and the process it was intended
         for. False to consume the event.
        """
        if not self.consuming_mouse_events or event.Injected:
            # Send the event to pub sub
            print 'MessageName:', event.MessageName
            print 'Message:', event.Message
            print 'Time:', event.Time
            print 'Window:', event.Window
            print 'WindowName:', event.WindowName
            print 'Position:', event.Position
            print 'Wheel:', event.Wheel
            print 'Injected:', event.Injected
            print '---'
            # Send the event to other handlers and its target
            return True
        else:
            # Consume the event. Any other hooks will not receive the event, nor will the process
            # the event was intended for.
            print 'Consumed mouse event'
            return False

    def thread_proc(self):
        print "Thread started"

        # Evidently, the hook must be registered on the same thread with the windows msg pump or
        #     it will not work and no indication of error is seen
        # Also note that for exception safety, when the hook manager goes out of scope, the
        #     documentation says that it unregisters all outstanding hooks
        self.hook_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
        self.hook_manager.KeyAll = self.on_keyboard_event
        self.hook_manager.HookKeyboard()
        self.hook_manager.MouseAll = self.on_mouse_event
        self.hook_manager.HookMouse()

        while self.started:
            pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()

        print "Thread exiting..."

        self.hook_manager.UnhookKeyboard()
        self.hook_manager.UnhookMouse()
        self.hook_manager = None

def main():
    hook_wrapper = WindowsHooksWrapper()
    hook_wrapper.start()
    hook_wrapper.consume_keyboard_events(True)
    hook_wrapper.consume_mouse_events(True)
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 50)
    pyautogui.moveTo(200, 200)
    time.sleep(30)

    hook_wrapper.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Expected to see mouse move print out in the output.

Comment: Similar question i have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328205/mouse-cursor-not-moving-in-selenium-python-having-pyautogui.

Comment: You found any solution?

Comment: I have not. I am still stuck on this one.